# Sending a sentance in AHK when a series of keys are pressed?

Tags: autohotkey

so at the moment I can send a sentence by pressing one letter key like:

```
^!#h:: send hello world
```

what i would like to be able to do is when i press a series of characters for it to type out a sentence. something like

> ^!#hello:: send hello world

Thank you,
Steve,

Comment: You could have it prompt you for the rest of series of characters after it sees the first one.

Comment: i found out how - ::hello::hello world - seems so obvious now :/ shame it only works after you press a key after it though.

Comment: Use the asterisk option for auto expansion `:*:hello::hello world`

Answer (score 0):

Hotstrings

```
::hello::hello world
```

To make it auto expand us the asterisk option

```
:*:hello::hello world
```

For the full set of options:
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options